# Microservice / REST fault tolerant communication

Tags: spring, rest

I have some microservices (spring mvc with rest templates), communicating with each other through REST (mainly asynchronously).

The problem is, I would like to add some fault tolerancy to the system; e.g. if one of the microservices is down while the other system is making a request, this request should automatically be retried later.

So, basically I'm looking for some kind of REST proxy, which:

- consumes REST request
- tries to deliver the message to its recipient
- if the delivery fails, will try again later

Are there any projects/libraries for this?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: it sounds like a messaging services or you have to write code using queue. If its expected to be very high volume and large bytes of data how about write all rest calls to database and write a daemon thread which reads database table and updates flag once read and calls rest service. (implementation of thread can read the source destination , request data , and response data). And of course clean that table on a regular basis.

Comment: Have a look at [Netflix ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon), [RxNetty](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty), they offer retry feature. For persisted retry, as stated by @surya, a message broker will be more suitable,

Comment: Client side solution could do the trick - the main reason I was thinking about a proxy, is that some of the microservices are not too reliable, so they might crash (a 3rd party proxy could crash too - but it not be that likely); so Ribbon could be nice, if it would have some kind of persistent-storage strategy.

Comment: Message brokers are nice, but I could not find any implementations, which are easily used through REST

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at ready to use solutions from Spring: Spring Cloud + Eureka + Hystrix  + Zuul + Ribbon
You can also use spring-retry with @Retryable @Recover annotations.

Comment: I just found Spring retry, which seems to be a very nice project (I wonder why is it not in Spring core ...?) - but instead of an in-memory client-side solution, I would rather have another microservice or a persistent client-side solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker and have some form of container orchestration (like docker swarm, kubernetes...) over mutliple host machines then you can have mutliple replicas of each microservice running, automatic recovery after failure, load balancing between the replicas and seemless networking (no need for server IP's just the microservice name).

This however also adds some complexity of having multiple replicas with the same application running (data consistency....).

However you could have a swarm (multiple servers) running with one replica of each service with data persisted on some external database or filesystem. Then when one of the servers dies or one of the services encounters a problem a new instance will spin up and all requests will wait for this spin up (Again the services don't know IP of each other just the name of the service they want to talk to, the orchestrator takes care of linking the services).

You could in the most simple setup also have a swarm with only one server and store anything on local DB or file system. The beauty is your setup would already be built with a technology that is capable of scaling.

Comment: Well, yes, this seems like a great idea - but I was thinking about a "smaller" solution :-)

Comment: Then maybe consider a swarm on one machine with one replica of everything. It is not so hard to implement this. But it consumes some memory. What you get is a system that restarts any service which crashes. This does not yet solve all your problems so I understand if its not the solution you're looking for.